# The Liquibase Exception: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, maven, liquibase

I can't get my function to work in the liquibase changeset.
This function is good working on the IntelliJ IDEA:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value() RETURNS varchar AS
$$
SELECT varchar '170d76f83d90ea1427' AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

But it fails when trying to run it in the liquibase changeset like this:

```xml
<changeSet author="akulik" id="test-014-002">
        <sql>
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value() RETURNS varchar AS
            $$
                SELECT varchar '170d76f83d90ea1427' AS result;
            $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            <sql>
                DROP FUNCTION get_secret();
            </sql>
        </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

I'm catching this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.2.2:update (default-cli) on project my_liquibase_project: Error setting up or running Liquibase: Migration failed for change set db/com/akulik/test/db/changesets/db.changelog-014.xml::test-014-002::akulik:
[ERROR]      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_secret() RETURNS varchar AS
[ERROR]      $$
[ERROR]             SELECT varchar '170d76f83d90ea1427' AS result: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
[ERROR]             SELECT varchar '170d76f83d90ea1427' AS result"
[ERROR]   Position: 68
[ERROR] ->
```

I think that I should correctly shield my function. I tried this way but it didn't work and I received the same error message.
I continue to find a solution in this way.

```xml
<changeSet author="akulik" id="test-014-002">
        <sql><![CDATA[
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value() RETURNS varchar AS
            $$
                SELECT varchar '170d76f83d90ea1427' AS result;
            $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
        ]]></sql>
        <rollback>
            <sql>
                DROP FUNCTION get_secret();
            </sql>
        </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about `<createProcedure>` [tag](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/create-procedure.html) and used it instead of `<sql>` tag in my changeset definition. That's resolved my problem. Now it's working fine.